# Use PDFJS DefaultTextLayerFactory and DefaultAnnotationLayerFactory from Angular4

Tags: angular, pdf.js

I have a web app written in Angular4 using typescript and it has been working well for me. I now try to change is to use the annotation layers and I can't figure out how to do that. I have changed my code to work like the pageviewer example.

I import pdf.js like this:

```
import * as PDFJS from 'pdfjs-dist';
```

I load the document like this:

```
this.loadingTask = PDFJS.getDocument(url);
this.loadingTask.onProgress = progress => this.downloadProgress = (progress.loaded / fileSize) * 80;
this.pdf = await this.loadingTask;
```

and then I render it like in the pageviewer example:

```
// Get size of current PDF page
const page = await this.pdf.getPage(currentPage);
let viewport = page.getViewport(1);

// Calculate the scale
let scale = 1;
if (zoomWidth) {
    scale = windowWidth / viewport.width;
} else {
    scale = Math.min(windowWidth / viewport.width, windowHeight / viewport.height);
}

// Creating the page view with default parameters.
var pdfPageView = new PDFJS.PDFPageView({
    container: container,
    id: currentPage,
    scale: scale,
    defaultViewport: page.getViewport(scale),
    // We can enable text/annotations layers, if needed
    textLayerFactory: new PDFJS.DefaultTextLayerFactory(),
    annotationLayerFactory: new PDFJS.DefaultAnnotationLayerFactory()
});
// Associates the actual page with the view, and drawing it
pdfPageView.setPdfPage(page);
return pdfPageView.draw();
```

When I run this I get det following error in the Chrome console:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_pdfjs_dist__.DefaultTextLayerFactory is not a constructor
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_pdfjs_dist__.DefaultTextLayerFactory is not a constructor
```

If I comment out DefaultTextLayerFactory and DefaultAnnotationLayerFactory I get a similar error on PDFPageView.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you got it resolved? if so please post your working solution for reference

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of studying of the pdf.js files I found a solution that works for me, and I post it here if it can help somebody else. I replaced

```
import * as PDFJS from 'pdfjs-dist';
```

with:

```
import 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf';
import 'pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer';
import pdfjsLib from 'pdfjs-dist/webpack';
declare let PDFJS;
```

and now it works in my Angular 4 app.